# Write in missing CRS without copying a file

Tags: python, rasterio

The coordinate system is not specified in a GeoTiff, but I know what it is. How do I edit the file using `rasterio` to write in the CRS? Copying it is one way (something like the following), but it's obviously not the best way:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.crs import CRS

with rasterio.open("path/to/file.tif") as src:
    src.crs = CRS.from_epsg(4326)
    with rasterio.open("path/to/file-copy.tif", "w", **src.profile) as dst:
        dst.write(src.read(1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply open the file in "r+" mode to edit the CRS.

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.crs import CRS

with rasterio.open("path/to/file.tif", "r+") as src:
    src.crs = CRS.from_epsg(4326)
```

Comment: Answer at https://rasterio.groups.io/g/main/message/453 credited to "Luke Pinner". Took me hours to find, so I wanted to record it for all.